# Mapping a subquery factory/CTE hierarchy result set to a Java Class

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, mapping, common-table-expression

```
public class Category {
      private String id;
      private String name;
      private Category parent;
      private Collection<Category> children;

//setters and getters...
}
```

SQL Query :

```
WITH CATEGORY_LINK(id,name,parent_id) AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id from CATEGORY
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM CATEGORY_LINK INNER JOIN CATEGORY ON (CATEGORY_LINK.id = CATEGORY.parent_id)
)
SELECT * FROM CATEGORY_LINK
JAVA:

    {
    ...
    List<Object[]> categoryRawData = sqlQuery.list();
    for(Object[] tuple : categoryRawData){
       String id = tuple[0];
       ...
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to map properly the given result set as `List<Object[]>` to `List<Category>` ? maybe there is an Hibernate feature to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you have a parent record, and many children records, you could make something like this:

```
from Category cat
left join fetch cat.parent p
```

and set the relation

```
<many-to-one name="parent" class="package.Category" column="CAT_ID" fetch="select" />
```

Set your attribute in your class as a

```
List<Category> children;
```

not Collection. You are going to have the object types you want.

Hope it helps to you